# FreeTDS - sudo uses different protocol version

Tags: sudo, odbc, freetds, unixodbc, sphinx

After a while of fiddling with FreeTDS I got my connection to MSSQL from Sphinx up and running as DSN-less connection.

After running

```
indexer index
```

Everything works as expected.

But, after running (which I have to run as sudo to use rotate)

```
sudo indexer index
```

My connection attempt ended with `DIAG [01000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Adaptive Server connection failed` which happened before as well until I changed tds protocol version to `8.0`. If I will use `DSN from freetds.conf` (instead of DSN-less connection) where I have explicitely set its version to `8.0` it works as expected.

It seems to me like `sudo` is using `different global configuration`, but I was unable to find more than one freetds config.

How can I force sudo to behave and use the correct protocol version?

EDIT:

I just discovered, that the whole thing worked only because I have used `export TDSVER=8.0` some time before...

But my question still stands - why does freetds ignores the version I have set in `[global]` part of config? `tsql -C` shows its version as `4.2`, could it be the problem?

And why doesnt sudo use the `TDSVER` I have set up (added it to /etc/environment) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$ sudo -E indexer index
```

Comment: Still the same behaviour

Comment: See my edited question please